# File deserialization with ServiceStack's TypeSerializer

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, windows-phone-8, servicestack

I use `ServiceStack.Text` as JSON library in my C# project and I'm trying to deserialize a string from file using it's `TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString`.

I have the following code:

```
async public static void TryLoad(Action<JsonArrayObjects> Ok, 
    Action<string> Fail, string key, int offset)
{
    try
    {
        var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var stream = await folder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(key);
        var result = await new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEndAsync();

        Debug.WriteLine(result);
        var cacheItem = TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString<CacheItem>(result);
        if (cacheItem.IsValid(offset) == true) Ok(cacheItem.Data); else Fail(key);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Fail(key);
    }
}
```

`Debug.WriteLine` here outputs correct JSON string but the next line with `TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString` yields an exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Unknown Module.
```

It seems like `TypeSerializer` gets an empty string. Why is it happening and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

If the Json is valid for your Object this might work as well:

```
 var cacheItem = (CacheItem) JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString(result, typeof (CacheItem));
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by switching to Json.NET which behaves correctly in this situation.