# Parsing JSON from file takes a lot of time

Tags: c#, json, performance, json.net, windows-phone-8

I have the following piece of code that loads a file with JSON from local folder and then parses it:

```
async public static void TryLoad(Callback Ok, Action Fail, string key, int offset)
{
    try
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        ItemsCache cacheItem;
        var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var stream = await folder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(key);
        using (stream)
        {
            var result = await new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEndAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine("Raw data loaded: " + (DateTime.Now - now).TotalMilliseconds);

            cacheItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemsCache>(result);
            Debug.WriteLine("Json has been parsed: " + (DateTime.Now - now).TotalMilliseconds);

            stream.Close();
        }

        bool isOK = cacheItem.IsValid(offset);
        if (isOK) Ok(cacheItem.Data); else Fail();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Fail();
    }
}
```

And `ItemsCache` itself:

```
public class ItemsCache
{
    public string Stamp { get; set; }
    public JToken Data { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid(int ofs)
    {
        DateTime moment = DateTime.Parse(Stamp);
        return (DateTime.Now - moment).TotalSeconds < ofs;
    }
}
```

Output after loading the data twice in a row:

```
Raw data loaded: 356,7372
Json has been parsed: 855,588
Raw data loaded: 1269,6079
Json has been parsed: 1300,8621
```

JSON:

```
{"Stamp":"26.01.2013 20:49:26","Data":[{"id":188357911,"user":123145, ... a few more more key-value pairs}, ... the rest of the objects]}
```

Thing is, the whole process takes about 750 milliseconds, 150 of them to load a raw data and 600 to parse it using Newtonsoft JSON library. The amount of data itself is small and contains about 20 serialized objects that are essentially a small key-value pairs (Although I've found out I could add a lot more data and it will not affect parsing time much).

Question is if it's normal to take that much time to load data and even more time to parse it? What could I do if it's not normal?

Comment: Please repeat the same steps twice inside the same process and measure each of the iterations and provide results in the question - there is a good chance that you are measuring time of initial JIT/code generation for deserialization, not actual parsing of JSON.

Comment: You can also try ServiceStack.Text JSON serialization library - it is even faster than Json.Net

Comment: @JoannaTurban I've tried and had problems with that library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106865/file-deserialization-with-servicestacks-typeserializer

Comment: Could you show the JSON you are trying to parse?

Comment: So second time parsing took 30ms - looks like there is a loot of things JSON.Net need to do on first deserialization of particular type (not surprising, similar to XmlSerialization)...

Comment: please use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch instead of DateTime for measuring.

Comment: @Jobo OK thanks, I'll read about it. I'm relatively new to wp development.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, you are right. Thing is I always see noticable delay in UI even when I call my cache function a few times in a row. It looks like LongListMultiSelector that displays objects also needs some substantial time to render them.

Comment: Is 600MS what you get back from putting a StopWatch class around the DeserializeObject() method call? Where does these numbers come from? Overall, 0.5s for JSON Serialization is pretty good. You can probably shave it down to 0.3s if you optimize your JSON and datatypes usage.

Comment: @JustinAngel Yes, ~600ms precisely for deserialization, but only on the first try. All the next times it takes only about 30ms as it turned out.